# How to run a single pre-commit hook with particular arguments that are different to the yaml definition

Tags: python, pre-commit.com

I know that I [can run a hook using](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run)

```
pre-commit run <hook id>
```

But if `<hook id>` is typically run with a set of arguments, and I want to run it with a different set, how should I go about that ?

For example, I might have a `black` hook that just runs with no arguments, but want to run it with `black --preview`.

Currently if I wanted to do that I would have black managed by my project venv *and* pre-commits venv, which seems overkill.

I guess I'm wondering if something like the following exists:

```
pre-commit run --just-call-the-package black --preview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-commit is designed so that all contributors to a repository run exactly the same tools and commands -- it is not a generalized environment manager and command runner.  that said you can customize the arguments for each tool using `args`:

```
# ...
    -   id: black
        args: [--preview]
```

though in black's case you probably instead want to use its configuration file

if you want to have one off "commands" with a separate fixed set of arguments you can utilize the `stages: [manual]` stage for a hook that won't normally run (but can be run manually)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit